# Error addListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an error

> location_marker.addListener is not a function

map initialization

```
   function initAutocomplete() {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 31.7917 , lng: 7.0926},
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
```

running through a list of locations and placing a marker for each

```
            var location_marker;
              for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                    location_marker = markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      title: locations[i].title,
                      position: locations[i].location

                    }));                         
              }
```

create an info window that displays every marker's title

```
                      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: location_marker.title
                      });
                      location_marker.addListener('click', function() {
                          infowindow.open(map, location_marker);
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, which does not seem complete, I assume the following.

Your `var locationMarker` saves the result from `markers.push` which returns the length of the array to which an object (`google.maps.Marker`) was pushed.

Because `locationMarker` is a Number, it has no `addListener` method. You might want to do something like this instead:

```
location_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  title: locations[i].title,
  position: locations[i].location

})
markers.push(location_marker);
```